# Multiple ajax call on codeigniter 3.1 showing 403 access forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Multiple ajax call on Codeigniter 3.1 showing 403 access forbidden. First ajax call is working fine but on success of first ajax call second ajax call is showing "**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)**". Any idea where i am doing wrong !

```
$(document).on({
        click: function() {
            var ___product_id = $(this).attr('data-item-id');
            var ___product_add_option = $(this).attr('data-option-type');
            var ___product_click_option = $(this).attr('data-click-option');
            alert(___product_click_option);
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxURL+'ajax_home/insert_form_item_to_cart',
                type: "POST",
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {'product_id':___product_id, 'product_add_option':___product_add_option,'product_click_option':___product_click_option,'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':csrf_value},
                success: function(_response){
                    $.post(ajaxURL + 'ajax_home/getProductCategory',{
                        'product_click_option':___product_click_option,
                        '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':csrf_value
                    },function(response,status){
                        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    });
                }, error: function(err){
                    alert('Error ' + err.name + 'Error ' + err.message + 'Error ' + err.description);
                }
            });
        }
    },'.__product_add_to_cart_option_normal_,.__product_add_to_cart_option_gift_');
```

Comment: Go to `config.php` and try to turn of CSRF token `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;`

Comment: hi, ya after doing that it's working , but where is wrong that not working

Comment: if you keep CSRF protection on, it will check CSRF token on every request, since your second request have outdated token it will redirect to 403. its very common problem with CI.

Comment: if you really want to use CSRF token, you should get updated CSRF token from server, on response of first AJAX, and use the received token to create new(second) AJAX. Its really complicated when we have multiple forms or AJAX requests on same page.

Comment: thanks, working now.  :)